# Potential energy on an equidistant line between two massive bodies

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, work, potential-energy

The situation is illustrated below:
[image]

The blue dot is an object with mass $m$, moving at constant speed on the equidistant line between the two masses $M$. The graph on the right shows how the potential energy of object $m$ changes as it moves along the line — gradually decreasing until it reaches a minimum at the centre of mass of the masses $M$.

Now so far so good, the problem arises when you examine the energy of mass $m$, in that its potential energy decreases without changing its kinetic energy, as the work done by the masses $M$ cancel each other out, and this seems to be a violation of the law of conservation of energy.

**What I've tried**

At first I thought the fallacy must lie within the assumption that the masses $M$ are not moving, which they most definitely are. However, after some more thought I realised this does not matter, because as long as the movement of the two masses are symmetrical, they still do zero work on mass $m$ overall. Indeed all it does is complicating the potential energy vs distance graph, yet the potential energy still changes without changing the kinetic energy.

Comment: If he object is moving at constant speed along that line, then there must be a *third* force acting on it.  Under the influence of just the gravitational force exerted by the other two masses, the object will speed up as it moves to the center-point and slow down as it moves away from the center point, consistent with the conservation of energy. The work done by the two masses do *not* cancel!  They are both positive while the object is moving towards the center and both negative while the object is moving away from the center.

Comment: By the way, if you find that the gravitational potential energy changes when the work done by the gravitational force is zero, then you're doing something wrong, because $\Delta P_{\textrm{grav}} = -W_{\textrm{by grav}}$, where you have to be careful about how you choose your system in order to interpret this statement.

Comment: @march haha thank you so much I don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in march's comments, your belief that the work done by the masses cancels is false. The change in potential energy is just the negative of the work it does $\Delta PE_{gravity} = -W_{gravity} $. At every point along the line (except the intersection with a line joining the two masses M) mass m is subject to a net force along its direction of motion. You can see this by vector addition of the forces from the two masses. This force does work $W = \int \mathbf{F}_{gravity} \cdot d \mathbf{s} = \Delta KE$ on m. The net force changes sign where potential energy has its minimum.

Energy will be conserved even if the two M masses are held static. In this case the forces acting on them will not act over any distance so $W = \int \mathbf{F} \cdot d \mathbf{s} = 0$. The situation where the bodies are free but $M \gg m$ will approximate this.

Comment: I do NOT know how didn't notice this hahaha tysm.